# How to get left edge scrolling on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

How do I configure Ubuntu 14.04 to use left edge scrolling instead of right edge scrolling? My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 14R.

EDIT

```
ubu@ubu:~$ synclient -l | grep 'Circ' 
CircularScrolling       = 0
CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
CircScrollTrigger       = 7
CircularPad             = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable left-edge scrolling, you can essentially follow @kos's suggestion. In my case i used something like:

```
synclient LTCornerButton=3 LBCornerButton=2 RTCornerButton=3 RBCornerButton=2 TapButton3=2 ClickFinger2=0 ClickFinger3=0 LockedDrags=0 VertEdgeScroll=1 HorizEdgeScroll=1 VertTwoFingerScroll=1 HorizTwoFingerScroll=1 CircularScrolling=1 CircScrollTrigger=1 PalmDetect=1 CircularPad=0
```

The left edge scrolling will be enabled in 'natural-mode' by default (I don't know why). But you can reverse this with a bit of effort.

First thing to do is to get the xinput id of the touchpad. The following code will give you that:

```
xinput list | egrep "slave.*pointer" | grep -v XTEST | sed -e 's/^.*id=//' -e 's/\s.*$//'
```

Now get the button-map of this device by:

```
xinput get-button-map <id-num-here>
```

This should give you something like:

```
  1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Now, if the numbers are indeed in order, this means that the scrolling is not reversed. What we need to do to reverse the scrolling, is reverse numbers 4 and 5, which represent the scroll wheel. To do this:

```
xinput set-button-map <id-num-here> 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

Now you're left-edge scroll should work properly.

If you want to reverse it to original state, you can use the same command as above by giving the original order of sequence.

As you might notice, this comes with a price - that your right-edge scrolling is now reversed! As the OP notes below, this can be reversed again to normal by enabling natural scrolling on mouse and touchpad settings.

Source: [This](https://n00bsys0p.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/reverse-xorg-scrolling-in-linux-natural-scrolling/) excellent blog post!

Comment: "As you might notice, this comes with a price - that your right-edge scrolling is now reversed!" I can undo it by enabling natural scrolling on mouse and touchpad settings. now ive got both edge scrolling! thanks

Answer (score 1):

**This works, however the scrolling type for circular scrolling is set by default to natural scrolling; see [Ron's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/672636/380067) to invert the scrolling direction**.

Circular scrolling is disabled by default;

First off, enable circular scrolling:

```
synclient CircularScrolling=1
```

(`synclient CircularScrolling=0` to disable it again)

At this point the circular scrolling should be set to be triggered on any edge;

Set the circular scrolling to be trigged only on the left edge of the touchpad:

```
synclient CircScrollTrigger=7
```

(`synclient CircScrollTrigger=0` to set it to be triggered on any edge again)

Other possible values for `CircScrollTrigger` from [X.org](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect3) are:

```
Option "CircScrollTrigger" "integer"
Trigger region on the touchpad to start circular scrolling
0   All Edges
1   Top Edge
2   Top Right Corner
3   Right Edge
4   Bottom Right Corner
5   Bottom Edge
6   Bottom Left Corner
7   Left Edge
8   Top Left Corner
Property: "Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger"
```

This will work only until reboot; to make the changes permanent, add the commands to `/etc/init/lightdm.conf` after the line `post-start script`:

```bsh
post-start script
    synclient CircularScrolling=1
    synclient CircScrollTrigger=7
    sleep 5
    clear > /dev/tty7
end script
```

Comment: Nothing happens when i run the command

Comment: @kernel_panic It's not supposed to output anything, have you tried scrolling on the left side? It works for me. If it doesn't please add the output of `synclient -l | grep '^[ ]*Circ' ` to your question

Comment: @kos2 I tried scrolling on the left, it didnt scroll

Comment: @kernel_panic Because you don't have `CircularScrolling` enabled, I assumed you have since you are able to scroll on the right side. Run `synclient CircularScrolling=1` and it should work.

Comment: I did as you told and left edge scrolling works, but in the reverse direction!

Comment: yes, this is different from how i was scrolling before and i have disables natural scrolling

Comment: Ok, run this: `synclient -l | grep '\(Vert\|Horiz\)ScrollDelta'` and note down the values; then invert them by running `synclient VertScrollDelta=[...]` and `synclient HorizScrollDelta=[...]`, that should do.

Comment: synclient -l | grep '\(Vert\|Horiz\)ScrollDelta'
    VertScrollDelta         = 112
    HorizScrollDelta        = 112

Comment: @kernel_panic Yes, now you should invert them. Run `synclient VertScrollDelta=-112` and `synclient HorizScrollDelta=-112`

Comment: Now its not even scrolling. its just juping up and down when i try to scroll

Comment: @kernel_panic It doesn't work for me either, however it doesn't "jump up and down" like you're describing, maybe you put in the wrong values? However apparently there's no way to invert it, I went through all this page at X.org (http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html#sect3) and found nothing. Sorry for now, I'll ping you if I find something else.